# Right click on datagridview and call edit form to edit selected row

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have a combobox and a textbox to filter my data and show them in a datagridview:

```
    AFDBEntities adbe = new AFDBEntities();

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var cbo = cmbInstallers.Text;
        switch (cbo){
            case "First Name":
                var ianst = (from x in adbe.TblInstallers
                         where x.FirstName.Contains(txtSearch.Text)
                         select x).ToList();
                dgvSearched.DataSource = ianst;
    }
```

and now when I have for example 4 results that contains "x", they all shown in datagridview.
I want to make right click option on datagridview that gives me a menu for opening a new form to edit selected row of results.

[Picture of Form](http://imaue.tk/up/2edc5c9e2103.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a context Menu to you DataGridView and then monitor its events through the Editing_Control_Showing Event Handle on the DataGridView.